# Python urllib2 open request fails with urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, urllib2

Below is my python code using urllib2 library and it keeps failing with an Unauthorized error although I am using the correct API key.  If I user curl, the POST/GET works just fine.Anyone got ideas? Thanks.

Adding the curl commands below that works just fine

```
Create Credential 
curl -X POST 'https://myurl.com' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -u 'XXXXXXXXXX:' \
     -d @- << EOF
{ 
  "vendorAccountId": "1234567",
  "type": "my_role"
}
EOF
```

Below is the python code which doesn't work.
Basically, the line of code where it is failing is: response = opener.open(request)

```
import boto3
import json
import logging
import signal
import requests
from urllib2 import build_opener, HTTPHandler, Request
import urllib2


LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def main():
        auth_token = "XXXXXXXXXX"
        account_id = "1234567"
        request_type = "CreateCredentials"
        content_type = ""
        request_body = json.dumps({})

         if request_type == "CreateCredentials":
            target_url = 'https://myurl.com'
            request_method = "POST"
            content_type = "application/json"
            request_body = json.dumps({
                "vendorAccountId": account_id,
                "type": "my_role"
            })

        handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

        request = urllib2.Request(target_url, data=request_body)
        request.add_header("Content-Type", content_type)
        request.add_header("Content-Length", len(request_body))
        request.add_header("Authorization", auth_token)
        request.get_method = lambda: request_method
        response = opener.open(request) #*****Fails here******


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you have a working curl request and a non-working urllib2 request, you should probably start by figuring out exactly what the difference is (there is one if one's working and the other isn't, even if it's not an obvious one).

Comment: Yes, that is the thing I am trying to find out. Its obviously the issue with the urllib2 implementation that is not working as stated. And I am trying to debug more on that? Do you have any suggestions? How do we print the request paramater?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. If you can figure that out and add that as well as the curl call you're using to the question, it should at least make it possible for someone to review and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Added the curl command in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what the issue was. My lack of patience for not reading the vendor manuals. The HTTP request I was sending was missing some parameters that was required and I needed to send the Key in an encrypted format too.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! If you could add the info that was tripping you up and then accept your own answer, it could be a great resource for others that may find this question while having similar problems in the future.